# Cannot copy file into ...windows/system32/en-US

Tags: windows-7, windows, permissions, uac

I have successfully edited the "winlogon.exe.mui" file through ResourceHacker software. But when I was trying to copy it back to overwrite the original "winlogon.exe.mui" file in **...Windows/system32/en-US**, I received an error right after the UAC permission. It says: "access denied."

I am on an administrative account, and I still receive that error. That's because I don't have ownership and permission over that folder to make changes to that folder(?).

Background:

> I want to change the Windows Logon and Logoff text, and that is the reason I am in need to copy and replace the file.

Q1 - If that is the case, how do I get that ownership and permission to copy the file?

Q2 - Is it safe to change permission and ownership?

both the questions above are related.

Comment: Did you try to change the permission and after to restore them? Consider that you can always start with a pen drive Linux system, modify the files and start again with Windows... This always if there is not a _checksum check_ on the files you are going to modify...

Comment: I am not restoring them. I copied the Original file. Edited it. Tried to copy it back to the same place, but got the "access denied" error. @Hastur

Comment: I didn't change the permission. That is my question. How do I? and is it safe? @Hastur

Comment: I cannot answer you about the safeness of each modification you can do on files that are supposed to be not modifiable. In general it is expected that to change a string in the welcome it will be not a problem. Backup your data and do your attempt. To change permission you can see the [technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754344.aspx) itself. :-)

Comment: I just changed the text from "Welcome" to "Not Welcome" and nothing else. @Hastur

Comment: You can read [here](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/126315-welcome-log-text-message-change.html). It seems it is not so difficult or dangerous. I can suggest you to try even instead of _"Welcome"_ a more friendly _"Go Away"_ (same length) :-)

Comment: @hastur I tried tht site. All the boxes are greyed out :(

Comment: Provide us the current permissions information on the file.

Comment: Do you run the _ResourceHacker_ executable elevated (right click => `Run as administrator`)?

Comment: @JosefZ Yes! I did.

Comment: @Ramhound I changed it somehow. Made "full control" on every user. When I tried to copy it, it didn't showed any copying bar. Just file selected.